# strnlen not declared in this scope on iOS 4.2.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, string

I have code that was using strnlen in a .mm file

The compiler when using Xcode 4.2 will work just fine to build.
Xcode 3.2.5 however cannot find strnlen()...

I have tried the solutions posted for strlen

```
#include <cstring> // doesn't work
using std::strlen; // doesn't work

#include <string> // doesn't work
```

Is there a way to use strnlen on iOS 4.2.1?

For now i'm just converting to NSString object and using length.

Comment: You can use xcode 4 to compile to ios 4, you know.

Answer (score 1):

Is there something wrong with using strlen, which is a standard C function?  I looked up strnlen and it seems to be a GNU extension.

Comment: Better yet, why not just continue to use NSString and avoid the headaches associated with C string handling?